# Web app framework to call command line program

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

We're designing a Java EE web app (to run on tomcat)

It's intended to be a web interface for a command line program. Is there any framework/application that allows this?

i.e. JSP pages which will internally fire commands to a program installed on the same server as the Tomcat server.

The command line is a propietary non-Java program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`java.lang.Runtime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and its `exec(..)` methods to start command-line programs.

Comment: yes - aware of that one. was hoping if any web framework allows this or have to write JSP > servlet code to do this?

Comment: @ktaylorjohn this is not web in nature, so I doubt there is a framework

Comment: @ktaylorjohn, there is nothing special about invoking native programs in regards to JEE settings.  Just do it in the usual fasion.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own, its pretty simple,

capture command from jsp,And execute it on server using

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);`

and send back the response

Answer (score 0):

I've found this article to be invaluable when using .exec

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

It has quite a lot of good example code, and shows many of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your security manager will probably restrict the use of Runtime.exec() inside of your application server...

Comment: It looks like it can work with Tomcat though which is my target server. http://readlist.com/lists/tomcat.apache.org/users/1/5083.html