# restart tomcat from a web site

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible for a Tomcat to restart it self?
I have a tomcat application. I'm adding a functionallity for the application to auto-update (the self application will download new war files). However, after this is done, I need to stop the application in order to modify the war.

I know that this can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Tomcat is configured in autoDeploy mode, then there is no need to stop Tomcat itself to deploy a new version of the war. You just need to somehow replace the old war with the updated version in the $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps folder. Tomcat will detect the new version and auto deploy it.

To store the updated war on your server, you can execute a script via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869766/web-app-framework-to-call-command-line-program). The script to run could be an ant task that deploys the new war file.

Comment: Last time I checked hot deploys were not recommended for production use--the old app doesn't always clean out completely and it could degrade the stability of your system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the manager application. It comes bundled with tomcat and allows restarting of contexts (apps).

[See here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart the tomcat process, then I think you will have to write a script and call it using Java [Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

If you just want to reload/restart certain webapps then you can use the [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).